# SwiftyJSON after forEach returns a weridly formatted array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I am trying to forEach an array of "Groups" after parsing the JSON with SwiftyJSON, after the forEach It gets returned as this:

```
("0", {
  "catagories" : [
    "test",
    "test2"
  ],
  "id" : "2353252352532",
  "_id" : "id",
  "members" : [
    "38272385353222",
  ],
  "name" : "Test"
})
```

My Code:

```
 case .success(let data):
             let res = JSON(data)
             print(res)
             res.forEach { group in
             print(group) }
```

original JSON:

```
[
  {
    _id: '5ef016ddae29d80bed06c6b3',
    id: '2353252352532',
    name: 'Test',
    catagories: [ 'test', 'test2' ],
    members: [ '38272385353222', '382572385353222', '6682510319551512576']
  }
]
```

Comment: forget about SwiftyJSON. You should take a look at Codable protocol

Comment: Please show your original JSON data, not some debugger/print output.

Comment: done, now showing orginal json

Comment: That's not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JSON is actually valid and looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5ef016ddae29d80bed06c6b3",
    "id": "2353252352532",
    "name": "Test",
    "catagories": [ "test", "test2" ],
    "members": [ "38272385353222", "382572385353222", "6682510319551512576"]
  }
]
```

try this to read/parse it:

```
struct Group: Codable {
    let id, groupID, name: String
    let categories, members: [String]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id"
        case groupID = "id"
        case name, categories = "catagories", members
    }
}

do {
  let groups = try JSONDecoder().decode([Group].self, from: data)
  groups.forEach { print($0) }
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```